# Open a pop up window on action link in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I want to Open a Crystal Report on Pop up Window on Menu Click

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Display Name", "Action","Controller", new { target="blank"})%>
```

This Above Code works, but it opens on a next tab.I need to open on a pop-up window.

Comment: where is above code?

Comment: Which code you are referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a a razor action link open in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851860/how-to-have-a-a-razor-action-link-open-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: may be [How to trigger window.open by Html.Actionlink in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35325285/2417602) will help.

Comment: If you are comfortable with bootstrap, you can use Modal popup - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved  by using the below code.

```
$('a.edit').click(function () {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=900,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
                return false;
            });

<%= Html.ActionLink("Display Name", "Action","Controller", new { @class="edit"})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
target="blank"
```

this thing is specially used for opening in new tab.....If you copied it unknowingly then remove this and its gonna open in same tab

Comment: i need to open in a popup window .now its opening in an next tab of the same broswer window

Comment: you have to use window.open()for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219325/javascript-jquery-open-current-link-in-pop-up-window

Comment: have a look at the link

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways doing it.
Use partial view:

steps: 
1. create a partial view to load report.
2. Decorate partial view div with bootstrap model class
3. on click of menu anchor write something below.

```
var reporturl = '/Home/Report';  
$(function () {  
    $("#reportMenu").click(function () {  

        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: reporturl,  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            data: { "Id": id },  
            datatype: "json",  
            success: function (data) {  
                $('#reportDiv').modal('show');                    

            },  
            error: function () {  
                console.log("Report load failed.");  
            }  
        });  
    });  
    $("#closbtn").click(function () {  
        $('#reportDiv').modal('hide');  
    });        
});  
 </script>
```